# How populate custom struct type from interface{} returned from reflections.GetField()?

Tags: go

My configuration (populated via viper) includes the following:

```
Puppet struct {
    Tasks struct {
        Task1 struct {
            FullTaskName string
            }
        Task2 struct {
            FullTaskName string
        }
    }
}
```

My code seeks to extract attributes for the appropriate task dynamically.
reflections.GetField() returns an empty interface, so in order to access the 'FullTaskName' attribute later on (say with 'pt.FullTaskName') I therefore need to either convert it, or assert, or something, to my custom type (as I poorly understand it).  Here I'm trying to convert.

```
type pTask struct {
    FullTaskName string
}

taskName := "Task1"

allTasks := conf.Puppet.Tasks
t, _ := reflections.GetField(allTasks, taskName)

pt := pTask(t)
```

But I can't figure out how to do it.  I've confirmed via the debugger that the value of 't' is as expected prior to my attempted assignment:

```
t = {interface{} | struct {...}} 
  FullTaskName = {string} "foobar"
```

However I get the following error when trying to assign & convert 't' to 'pt':

```
"Cannot convert an expression of the type 'interface{}' to the type 'pTask'"
```

I've tried asserting it as well but it also fails ('ok' == false).

It looks to me like my custom type matches the values in the returned interface{}, in that they have the same attributes with the same names.   There are no methods attached to my 'pTask' type.  What am I not understanding?

Comment: To get the dynamic value stored in an interface you need to use a [type assertion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions), but you also need to know the value's dynamic type. However it's unlikely to be a type different from the one stored in the value from which you got the interface. So if the field has an unnamed struct then you should also use an unnamed struct in the type assertion. e.g. `t.(struct {FullTaskName string})`.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/OJ8jctSN53x

Comment: Thanks I've got it now.   The 'struct {...}' meant it was getting an unnamed struct, which is not compatible with my custom type.  I've just changed my config so there's a custom type there as well and it now works.